# How to set to update a column in a table that have more than one same value

Tags: sql

I am trying to update a temporary table in a stored procedure, so in the set clause of the update, I used an inner join to update one column, but since that column has some same value the update gets repeated. How I can get the update only for the first unique value of the column?

Here is what I've done for the update:

```
select
    style, color,item, prodnocompany, WIP, 0 As Inventory
into
    #protable
from
    prodorderheader poh
inner join
    prodorderdetal pod on poh.prodno = pod.rpodno

select
    item, sum(QOHQTY) as Inventory
into
    #Inve
from
    inventory
group by
    item

update p
set p.Inventory += i.Inventory
from #prod p
inner join #Inve i on p.item = i.item
```

I need to get the following result:

| Style | item | Inventory |
| --- | --- | --- |
| D3623M | 123776 | 12 |
| D3623M | 123665 | 11 |
| T3445S | 122099 | 10 |
| D3565W | 133422 | 12 |
| D3565W | 133422 | 0 |

In the #Prod table there may be some repeating of style and item, because they have a different *prodnocompany*, but in Inventory, each item has a specific quantity on the had amount (which is QOHQTY), but what I got from the update is as below:

| Style | item | prodnocompany | Inventory |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| D3623M | 123776 | 234 | 15 |
| D3623M | 123665 | 211 | 11 |
| T3445S | 122099 | 122 | 10 |
| D3565W | 133422 | 456 | 12 |
| D3565W | 133422 | 432 | 12 |

How can I update for the first item if I have the same item for different *pronocompany*s?

Answer (score 0):

As an option, add the rank to the #prod table and then take only the first (last row) for updating.
For example, so:

```
declare
    @t table (col varchar (100), i int)

declare
    @t2 table (rn int, col varchar (100), i int)

insert into @t
select 'A', 100
union all
select 'B', 100
union all
select 'C', 200
union all
select 'C', 300

insert into @t2
select DENSE_RANK()over (partition by col order by i), * from @t

select * from @t2 t
where t.rn in (select min(t_s.rn) from @t2 t_s where t_s.col=t.col group by col)
```